# Ставить ли знаки препинания рядом со смайлами?

Tags: пунктуация

Навеяно недавней темой. Понятно, что официальной точки зрения пока что быть не может. Но всё-таки очень интересно, как наиболее корректно ставить смайлы рядом со знаками препинания ?

Как написать лучше:

> Привет! :)

(смайл перед знаком препинания) или

> Привет :) !

(смайл после знака препинания) или

> Привет :)

(смайл вместо знака препинания)

Естественно, пример утрированный, но общую суть должен отражать.

Также, интересно, как лучше ставить смайл рядом с точкой (может ли смайл сам являться знаком препинания, что отменяет необходимость ставить точку, или точка всё-таки необходима)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я смайлами пользуюсь крайне редко - и только там, где без них просто невозможно или очень громоздко. Но вообще-то есть общий принцип, используемый, например, для постановки скобок или сносок. Если смайлик относится ко всей фразе, то он ставится после знака, если к одному слову - то перед. Во всяком случае так понятно всем.

Answer (score 2):

Я ставлю смайлы всегда после всех знаков препинания - в самом конце. А вообще, мне кажется, смайл ставится там, где необходима эмоция.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, если использовать и смайл, и знак препинания, лучше не разрывать знак препинания от слова:

*Привет! :) (и смайл через пробел)*

В принципе, думаю, смайл вполне может и заменить знак препинания, особенно точку:

*Привет :)*

А может заменить и восклицательный знак:

Привет =))))

Но это все, конечно же, только на разговорном уровне.

Comment: >Но это все, конечно же, только на разговорном уровне.  

А что, появились уже литературные смайлики? ;-))

Comment: Это так... Навеяно другим вопросом (http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/8295/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B) по поводу претензии смайлика на официальный статус :))